# Knp menu translations

Tags: symfony, internationalization, knpmenubundle

According to knp, [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/i18n.html) should be how you can easily add translations to your menu. It ain't working for me.
My menu class:

```
public function createMainMenuLeft(array $options)
    {
        $menuLeft = $this->factory->createItem('root', array('childrenAttributes' => array('class' => 'left')));

        $menuLeft->addChild('test', array('route' => 'test_route'))
            ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'AppBundle');

        return $menuLeft;
    }
```

In AppBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml I have

```
test: nothing
```

However, my menu still has the label 'test' not the value from the translations file. Am I missing something here?

My locale is set in `config.yml` to `en`.

Comment: have you tried without set the extra translation domain?

Comment: @Matteo yes, I did. Not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found the way to do it inside the documentation from the bundle, not the one from symfony. The template hast to be overwritten. [Source](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/v2.1.1/Resources/doc/i18n.rst)